# calculating distance and angle between vectors in keras LSTM

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, lstm

[image]I am using keras to detect similarity between question pairs. The model structure seems to be working fine but it gives me error on model.fit function. I even checked the datatype of my input data and it is numpy.ndarray. Any pointers in this regard and I'll be grateful.

> ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays
>   that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected.
>   Expected to see 1 arrays but instead got the following list of 2
>   arrays: [array([[    0,     0,     0, ...,   251,    46,    50],
>          [    0,     0,     0, ...,     7,    40,  6935],
>          [    0,     0,     0, ...,    17,   314,  2317],
>          ..., 
>          [    0,    ...

```
def Angle(inputs):

    length_input_1=K.sqrt(K.sum(tf.pow(inputs[0],2),axis=1,keepdims=True))
    length_input_2=K.sqrt(K.sum(tf.pow(inputs[1],2),axis=1,keepdims=True))
    result=K.batch_dot(inputs[0],inputs[1],axes=1)/(length_input_1*length_input_2)
    angle = tf.acos(result)
    return angle

def Distance(inputs):

    s = inputs[0] - inputs[1]
    output = K.sum(s ** 2,axis=1,keepdims=True)
    return output    




y=data.is_duplicate.values
tk=text.Tokenizer()
tk.fit_on_texts(list(data.question1.values)+list(data.question2.values))


question1 = tk.texts_to_sequences(data.question1.values)
question1 = sequence.pad_sequences(question1,maxlen=MAX_LEN)

question2 = tk.texts_to_sequences(data.question2.values)
question2 = sequence.pad_sequences(question2,maxlen=MAX_LEN)


word_index = tk.word_index
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
num_features = 300
num_workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
context_size = 5
downsampling = 7.5e-06
seed = 1
min_word_count = 5
hs = 1
negative = 5


Quora_word2vec = gensim.models.Word2Vec(

    sg=0,
    seed=1,
    workers=num_workers,
    min_count=min_word_count,
    size=num_features,
    window=context_size,  # (2 and 5)
    hs=hs,  # (1 and 0)
    negative=negative,  # (5 and 10)
    sample=downsampling  # (range (0, 1e-5). )

)

Quora_word2vec = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin',binary=True)
embedding_matrix=np.zeros((len(word_index)+1,300))

for word , i in tqdm(word_index.items()): #i is index

    try:

        embedding_vector =  Quora_word2vec[word] #Exception is thrown if there is key error
        embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector

    except Exception as e:  #If word is not found continue

        continue
```

## --------question1--------

```
model1 = Sequential()
print "Build Model"

model1.add(Embedding(
    len(word_index)+1,
    300,
    weights=[embedding_matrix],
    input_length=MAX_LEN
    ))

model1.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.2))
model1.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(300, activation='relu')))
model1.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.sum(x, axis=1), output_shape=(300,)))

print model1.summary()
```

#---------question2-------#

```
model2=Sequential()

model2.add(Embedding(
    len(word_index) + 1,
    300,
    weights=[embedding_matrix],
    input_length=MAX_LEN
    ))  # Embedding layer
model2.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.2))
model2.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(300, activation='relu')))
model2.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.sum(x, axis=1), output_shape=(300,)))


print model2.summary()


#---------Merged------#

#Here you get question embedding

#Calculate distance between vectors
Distance_merged_model=Sequential()
Distance_merged_model.add(Merge(layers=[model1, model2], mode=Distance, output_shape=(1,)))

print Distance_merged_model.summary()

#Calculate Angle between vectors

Angle_merged_model=Sequential()
Angle_merged_model.add(Merge(layers=[model1,model2],mode=Angle,output_shape=(1,)))

print Angle_merged_model.summary()


neural_network = Sequential()
neural_network.add(Dense(2,input_shape=(1,)))
neural_network.add(Dense(1))
neural_network.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

print neural_network.summary()


neural_network.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('weights.h5', monitor='val_acc', save_best_only=True, verbose=2)

print type(question1)
print type(question2)
neural_network.fit([question1,question2],y=y, batch_size=384, epochs=10,
                 verbose=1, validation_split=0.3, shuffle=True, callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

Comment: Your `neural_network` accepts an input of shape `(nb_of_examples, 2)` whereas you are providing a list of two `numpy` arrays. This is the direct reason of your error. Could you provide more details on what you are trying to achieve? You defined loads of functions but in the end - you try to fit the simplest network possible.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko I have added my architecture in the image above. This is what I am trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not connecting your final two layers into the dense and just having your neural network be the only network having data passed into since you are compiling and fitting on that layer with out having the distance and angle networks connecting to your final dense.

Everything with getting network #1 and #2 seem correct into the merge layers but you need to do something similar to:

```
neural_network = Sequential()
neural_network.add(Merge([Distance_merged_model, Angle_merged_model], mode='concat'))
neural_network.add(Dense(2,input_shape=(1,)))
neural_network.add(Dense(1))
neural_network.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

Comment: Glad to help :)